# Get list of venues of whole city

Tags: foursquare

How I can receive all venues in city (for example, in Moscow).
I am trying to get list of all venues via https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?near=Moscow,Russia&radius=20000&limit=50&&offset=0&client_id=clid&client_secret=clsecret&v=20160307
http requsts by changing offset parameter, but totalCount of venues in result list is 249 (for Moscow it is small).
So, is it possible to get list of all venues for so huge city as Moscow? 
It is neccesary for my bachelor work, I write a reccomendation system for building tourist routes and only foursquare service have a extensive database with cafes, museums and monuments.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking into the [documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/) and [Support](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/support)?

Comment: Yes, but as I understand the support of foursquare monitors requests with filter "foursquare".